# I want to clean my data in one go, but the following code doesn't work in R

Tags: r, if-statement, sapply

I want to clean my data in one go, but the following code doesn't work. Data has factor features and numeric features as well.

```
findnullna <- function(x) {
  for(i in 1:length(x)) {
    if(x[i]=="" | x[i]=="NULL" | x[i]=="#N/A" | x[i]=="#NAME?") {
      x[i] <- NA
    }
  }
  return(x)
}


df <- sapply(df,findnullna)
```

I get an error

> Error in if (x[i] == "" | x[i] == "NULL" | x[i] == "#N/A" | x[i] ==
>   "#NAME?") { :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

also sometimes I get

> Error in x[i] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Comment: Could you please 'dput()' your data? rep reducible would help all of us :)  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: You should use the `na.strings` argument of `read.table` (or whatever function you use for import).

Comment: Aside from any incompatibilities in your data (which we can only guess unless you provide a reasonable example), you should use `ifelse(x %in% c("", "NULL", ...), NA, x)` instead of your `for`-loop solution.